# How do I get rid of all the invisible/black stuff on this render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor

[image]

I tried compositing, changing render settings, etc. None of them worked. Is there a setting in which can fix this?

Comment: Please show your complete node tree for materials. It seems to  me you are not using the alpha channel on the texture to control transparency. Read: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Comment: Ok, Blender gave me something useful. SOrry to waste your time, guys...